# Style.Numberformat.Format with EPPLUS not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, formatting, epplus

Here's my piece of code

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Title");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataToExcel, true);

    int colNumber = 1;

    foreach (DataColumn col in dataToExcel.Columns)
    {
        if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            ws.Column(colNumber++).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd.mm.yyyy";
        }
    }
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Report.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

What I want is that my DataTable column that is of type DateTime gets formatted like - "dd.mm.yyyy". I used EPPLUS before in my winform application, and it worked (with the same code for date formatiting), and now, after creating my date column, it looks like this "42810,57377". Anyone had problems like this? 
Also, it does get set, but not displayed like I expect it to.

Comment: Aren't you setting the Format to the wrong column? because if the column is not a DateTime, it does not increment `colNumber`

Comment: @VDWWD Yes I am. I need to get rubber duck, so I wouldn't post problems like this again. Thank you :)